# Transaction Spring XD

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I'm working on a module which consumes some HTTP resources, write in a postgres, and finally push a message to the message bus (RabbitMQ).

I would like to figure out how to deal with transactions inside a module: how to encapsulate my postgres operation and the push to RabbitMQ (i.e in case the message could not be push to RabbitMQ my DB operation should be rollbacked) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques to wrap parts of a Spring Integration flow in a transaction; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395525/how-to-make-an-arbitrary-part-of-a-message-flow-pseudo-transactional/34398607#34398607) for some examples.

You must, of course, use direct channels throughout.

Comment: Thx Gary I will test it. I also heard some idea to provide a feature to keep module status.

Comment: What about the transacted property from XD ?

Comment: That just makes the rabbitmq interactions run in a transaction - it has nothing to do with the DB stuff in your module and, frankly, rabbitmq transactions do not provide a lot of value at the expense of degraded performance.